# Is it possible to map a xml-field to the node language selection field in drupal with Feeds and XPath?

Tags: 7, feeds, i18n-l10n

So, I've put together an XML import with the [Feeds module](http://drupal.org/project/feeds) and the [Feeds XPath Parser plugin](http://drupal.org/project/feeds_xpathparser). I've got everything set up and working and the eventdata from my XML is importing nicely to my content type in the main language of the website.

But, now I would like to import the eventdata in multiple languages. I've got a tag in the XML that contains the language but it seems I can't map the languagetag to the language selection field on my nodes with XPath.

I could create a new field to hold the language in my content type I guess but that feels like an odd solution.

Any ideas?

Thanks